# Ant failed to build on linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ant, junit

I hope someone can help me out with this problem.
I am using an Ant script to compile my java code but I get the following errors:

```
[junitreport] Processing /home/sander/workspace/AntIntro/reports/junit/TESTS-TestSuites.xml to /tmp/null1570204945<br />
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/usr/share/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl<br />
[junitreport] : Error! The first argument to the non-static Java function 'replace' is not a valid object reference.<br />
[junitreport] : Error! Cannot convert data-type 'void' to 'reference'.<br />
[junitreport] : Fatal Error! Could not compile stylesheet<br />
[junitreport] Failed to process /home/sander/workspace/AntIntro/reports/junit/TESTS-TestSuites.xml
```

I'm using:
 - Eclipse 3.7.2
 - OpenJDK 7
 - Archlinux x64
 - JUnit 4
 - Ant 1.7.2

Hopefully someone can help me out, thanks in advance

Comment: See the answers from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607151/error-the-first-argument-to-the-non-static-java-function-replace-is-not-a-val

Answer (score 0):

See my previous comment. It's a known issue, the workaround was to use apache-ant-1.8.3 with JDK-7 or apache-ant-1.8.2 with JDK-6.

Comment: I run ant from the command line now, this seems the only solution to fix this problem.