# Getting error as "Error! The first argument to the non-static Java function 'replace' is not a valid object reference"

Tags: selenium

Getting error as "Error! The first argument to the non-static Java function 'replace' is not a valid object reference" while generating the Junit report in eclipse. 
my system configuration is: Windows 8, JDK1.7

Please if any one knows answer, reply me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be more specific about your question. What does your code/config look like and exactly how does the error look?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error! The first argument to the non-static Java function 'replace' is not a valid object reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607151/error-the-first-argument-to-the-non-static-java-function-replace-is-not-a-val)