# junit error in eclipse with java 1.7 and ant 1.9

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit

I'm using Ant to run a series of tests and generate HTML reports using JUnit. I get the following error:

```
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] : Error! The first argument to the non-static Java function 'replace' is not a valid object reference.
[junitreport] : Error! Could not compile stylesheet
[junitreport] : Fatal Error! Cannot convert data-type 'void' to 'reference'. Cause: Cannot convert data-type 'void' to 'reference'.
```

I've seen this bug in other answers, but they pointed it out as a bug introduced with Java 1.6. I have the following set up:

- Java JDK: 1.7.0_55
- Ant: 1.9.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error! The first argument to the non-static Java function 'replace' is not a valid object reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607151/error-the-first-argument-to-the-non-static-java-function-replace-is-not-a-val)

Comment: That's the question I was referring to seeing-- all of the answers appeared to be either update java or update ant. Since I have a 1.9 version of Ant, is the protocol to add my issue in the comments to that one, or open a new question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse runs ant files with it's own packaged version of ant unless you tell it otherwise. Updated my eclipse platform (and thus the pre-packaged ant) and it ran fine.